# How can I make my fading backgrounds the same size on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been trying to make a simple website with a fading effect tied to scrolling the page:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 1000) {
    $('#img2').fadeIn({});
  } else {
    $('#img2').fadeOut('fast')
  };

  if (y > 2000) {
    $('#img3').fadeIn({});
  } else {
    $('#img3').fadeOut('fast')
  };

  if (y > 3000) {
    $('#img4').fadeIn({});
  } else {
    $('#img4').fadeOut('fast')
  };

  if (y > 4000) {
    $('#img5').fadeIn({});
  } else {
    $('#img5').fadeOut('fast')
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black url('https://via.placeholder.com/500x300?text=img1');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#img1,
#img2,
#img3,
#img4,
#img5 {
  margin: 0px !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  object-fit: fill;
  align-content: center !important;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300?text=img1">
  <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100?text=img2">
  <img id="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100?text=img3">
  <img id="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100?text=img4">
  <img id="img5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100?text=img5">
</body>

</html>
```

Which produces this result once I scroll "into" the next background:
[image: Image link]

As you can see, the overlapping background images don't fully cover the first background. I've been reading about CSS tags and properties but I haven't been able to work it out. Any pointers from someone more experienced than me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force the size of your images to cover the entire viewport with the following CSS properties:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

If you want to keep the ratio of your images, set `object-fit` to `cover` instead of `fill`.

You may also want to add `background-position: center` to your CSS background to center the image to the viewport.

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/8x6Ljc4e/

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Your solution didn't work for me unfortunately. However, since it did work in your jsfiddle it probably is a local issue with the images on my end. I'll take a look into it and I'll update this thread as soon as i find a solution.

Comment: Solved. Error was on my part, missed a semicolon of course. Thank you very much for your help.